# Filter the results search page with checkboxes of taxonomies (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem on my website.

The code below displays the ids of the posts which contain the term of the `country` taxonomy writen by the user.

For instance, if I search "france", or if I write `http://www.mywebsite.com/pagesearch/?country=france`, the ids 430, 522, and 650 containing the term `france` will display.

What I want is, when results are displayed, that some dropdowns of checkboxes appear on the results page, to be able to filter again the results. I have taxonomies `city` and `activity`. 
I would like that, if a user checks "Paris" and "Marseille" in the city taxonomy and "restaurants" in the activity taxonomy, it displays filtered results, with a OR condition on these terms.

For the moment I have this code: ($output is the dropdown with the city terms).
I don't know how to fetch the checked checkboxes and filter again the results with these terms.
I tried using

Thanks a lot for your help,

Marine

```
if ((isset($_GET['country'])) && (!empty($_GET['country']))){
    $country = sanitize_text_field($_GET['country']);      
    $search_posts_id = array();

        $search_args = array(
            'fields' => array('ids', 'post_type'),
            'post_type' => 'my_custom_posttype',
            'tax_query' => array(
            array (
            'taxonomy' => 'country',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $country,
            ),
     ),
        );
    $search_query = new WP_Query($search_args);

    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) :
            $search_posts_id = array_unique(wp_list_pluck( $search_query->posts, 'ID' ));
            $termobjs = wp_get_object_terms( $search_posts_id, 'city', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all'));


            $output ='<dl class="dropdownfilter"><dt><a href="#"><span class="hida">Marque</span><p class="multiSel"></p></a></dt><dd><div class="mutliSelect"><ul>';

            foreach($termobjs as $term){
                $output .= '<li><input type="checkbox" id="'.$term->slug.'" name="'.$term->taxonomy.'" value="'.$term->slug.'"> '.$term->name.'</li>';
            }
            $output .='</ul></div></dd><button class="buttonfilter">Filtrer</button></dl>';


    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 

    echo $output;
    echo $search_posts_id;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use that code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I use this code, and if I write for example http://www.mywebsite.com/pagesearch/?country=france, results containing the taxonomy term "france"are displayed on the results page, and a dropdown with checkboxes of all the french cities appear.  What I would like now is to get the checked  cities and to re-filter the search to display results, still with the term "france", but also with the checked terms "paris" and "marseille" from the city taxonomy, for example.

Comment: Ok, well that's a lot of steps and a lot of coding work. So if I were you I would break this process down into various smaller chunk, then deal with each one at a time. Then when you have completed one step, post another question for the next step. Then you can give specific details related to that step and show what code you have and explain what's happening compared to what you expect to happen. Otherwise, it's far too much work for someone to write all this code for you.